# In Eclipse / STS / maven, where do I define the deployed servlet name?

Tags: eclipse, maven, servlets, spring-tool-suite

I have the Eclipse (STS) with Maven installed.  I've named the project ExchangeBoardRest.  When I run the program from the embedded VMWare tc server it deploys to localhost:8080/ExchangeBoardRest/index.jsp, etc.  I don't want it there but in localhost:8080/exchangeboard/index.jsp.

I'm not seeing where I can change this.  I figured perhaps the pom.xml  would do this for me (I update the maven project right afterwards).  I don't have ExchangeBoardRest in any interesting text files (just in .settings, .project).

I don't want to have to edit the server.xml that VmWare tc creates.  Is there something easy I'm missing?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using STS, but Eclipse and m2e with WTP. But I guess it's the same thing:

- Right-click on the project in the project explorer and select **Properties**.
- Locate **Web project settings**
- Change **Context root** setting as you desire.

Comment: Yep, it is there.  Eclipse isn't my idea of well organized, but I gotta use it.  Thanks.